# automappewr map null value to destination if source value is zero

Tags: c#, automapper, nul

Im mapping from a dto to a view model.  The dto has a double property, if this value is zero I want to map it as null (this stops infragistics graph plotting a point in case of null, so nothing gets displayed )

I have this but it doesnt work I need it to map to null

```
.ForMember(x => x.AveragePrice, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(src =>
            {
                if(src.AveragePrice == 0)
                {
                    //need null here
                   return double.NaN;
                }
                else
                {
                    return src.AveragePrice;
                }

            }));
```

Comment: you can't return null if your `src.AveragePrice` isn't `Nullable<double>`

Comment: Could you implement a `double?` for your DTO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a resolver. You can use just MapFrom.

Also make sure that your AveragePrice property is of `double?` type in your view model.

```
.ForMember(x => x.AveragePrice, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.AveragePrice == 0 ? (double?)null : Math.Abs(src.AveragePrice)))
```

Comment: that worked thanks, I have one more question though, I need to check multiple conditions.  If the source is zero, map null, if its a negative value, make it positive.  I know automapper has multiple conditions but i cant figure out how to apply it in this case, can anyone help me out ?

Comment: @proteus For this particular scenario you even don't need a second check - you can just call `Math.Abs`. See my updated answer

Comment: doh ! that was so simple, why didnt  I think of that :-)  thank you